# Drupal: show Content just if User is on specific Language version

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, multilingual

I have a Drupal-Site with 2 different Language versions (DE & EN).
They use different Domains. I want to make sure, that German content can only be viewed if the User uses the German domain. So if a guy who uses my English page calls some German content, he should get a 404 page. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way might be adding following condition in the preprocess_node hook of your custom module:

```
if(!($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "www.german-site.com" && $vars['node']->language == "DE")
&& !($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "www.english-site.com" && $vars['node']->language == "EN")
){
    drupal_set_header('HTTP/1.1 404 Gone');
    print theme('page', 'Requested page not found.', FALSE);

}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Just this "drupal_set_header" does not work for Drupal7, so I need to find an other Solution there...

Comment: In drupal 7, you can use `drupal_add_http_header`.

Answer (score 0):

You should select a language when you add the content. And same will be available to respective language!